# Debian Lenny, Python 2.7 and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, debian-lenny

I am running a Debian Lenny box, which comes with Python 2.5.2.  I would like to run Python 2.7 for my WSGI apps *only*, keeping 2.5 as default for the system, but I cannot get it to work.

First, I installed Python 2.7.2 from source into `/usr/local`:

```
Python-2.7.2 # ./configure --enable-shared
[…]
Python-2.7.2 # make
[…]
Python-2.7.2 # make altinstall
[…]
```

Calling `python2.7` now from the command line works without any problems.  It also finds packages installed via `pip` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/packages`.

Next, I built `mod_wsgi` and copied it manually to the Apache module directory, so as not to touch files placed by `apt-get`.

```
mod_wsgi-3.3 # ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
[…]
mod_wsgi-3.3 # make
[…]
mod_wsgi-3.3 # cp .libs/mod_wsgi.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7
mod_wsgi-3.3 # cd /usr/lib/apache2/modules
modules # ln -sf mod_wsgi.so-2.7 mod_wsgi.so
modules # ldd mod_wsgi.so-2.7
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff08f53000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00002b0317e1f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b03181fd000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b031841a000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b031861e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00002b0318821000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002b0318aa5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b03179cd000)
```

I then modified `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.conf` and added the following directive:

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
    […]
    WSGIPythonHome /usr/local
    […]
</IfModule>
```

(Of course, `wsgi.conf` is symlinked in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.)

Finally, I restarted apache, but my WSGI scripts won’t run.  I get the following traceback in Apache’s error log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=20746): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/path/to/script.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.5.egg/flask/app.py", line 1306, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.5.egg/flask/app.py", line 1295, in wsgi_app
    return response(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.6.2-py2.5.egg/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 1017, in __call__
    start_response(status, headers)
TypeError: expected byte string object for status, value of type str found
```

I also tried the test WSGI script found in the [Installation Issues](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions) section of `mod_wsgi`’s documentation, but I get the same `TypeError` here.  Judging from the traceback, I would guess that Apache now runs Python 2.5 in combination with `mod_wsgi` compiled for 2.7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.  `mod_python` was also loaded, disabling it did the trick.  As it is the vanilla `mod_python` shipped with Lenny’s Apache, it is compiled against Python 2.5.2—naturally, this cannot work in combination with `mod_wsgi` compiled against a different version.

Comment: if this was your solution, you should accept your own answer. and welcome to serverfault :)

Comment: Thanks, Michael, for the warm welcome.  I cannot answer my own question within an 48 hour timespan, though. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Make sure the `PATH` inherited by the Apache user account sees the Python2.7 `/bin` and not the older version.

http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/svn/branches/mod_wsgi-1.X/README

"If you have multiple versions of Python installed and you are not using
that which is the default, you may have to organise that the PATH inherited
by the Apache application when run will result in Apache finding the
alternate version. Alternatively, the WSGIPythonExecutable directive should
be used to specify the exact location of the 'python' executable
corresponding to the version of Python compiled against. If this is not
done, the version of Python running within Apache may attempt to use the
Python modules from the wrong version of Python."

Other than that there is nothing that can be done aside from running another debian inside debian.

http://www.eggdrop.ch/texts/uml/

Having Nginx reverse proxy to the different virtual environments.

Comment: According to the Documentation (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonExecutable), the `WSGIPythonExecutable` directive is deprecated.  Furthermore, the section about Multiple Python Versions (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions) discourages modifying the `PATH` environment variable for Apache.  This is why I didn’t go for any of these proposed solutions.